# How can I add tick lines with values numbers to the custom slider?

Tags: c#, winforms

The custom slider is in this question link: [How to draw a custom slider control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70465326/how-to-draw-a-custom-slider-control)

The answer was great, and everything is working perfect.
Now I want to add to it ticks lines and near each tick line a number value.  similar to trackBar.

I'm not sure even how to get to it.  If to draw the ticks in a paint event? how to add the values numbers? How to make it dynamic so if I'm changing the slider size in the form1 designer the ticks and numbers will be changed with it. But first just adding ticks and numbers like in this trackbar.  This image screenshot is just example to show how I want to add the ticks and numbers.

TrackBar example to show how the ticks lines and numbers should be on the slider:

[image: trackBar example]

This is the code I tried in the OnPaint event.  the problem is that the numbers are too small. and if I change the slider size in the form1 designer then the numbers get bigger too.  but when the slider is smaller the numbers almost can't be seen.

if I'm changing the size in this line then the number get bigger but then part of each number swallow on the top.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public static class GraphicsExtensions
    {
        public static void DrawCircle(this Graphics g, Pen pen,
                                      float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                          radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }

        public static void FillCircle(this Graphics g, Brush brush,
                                      float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(brush, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                          radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
    }

    public class CustomSlider : Control
    {
        private float _radius;
        private PointF _thumbPos;
        private SizeF _barSize;
        private PointF _barPos;
        private List<float> lightningPositions = new List<float> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // Add your lightning positions here

        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

        public CustomSlider()
        {
            // This reduces flicker
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private float _min = 0.0f;
        public float Min
        {
            get => _min;
            set
            {
                _min = value;
                RecalculateParameters();
            }
        }

        private float _max = 1.0f;
        public float Max
        {
            get => _max;
            set
            {
                _max = value;
                RecalculateParameters();
            }
        }

        private float _value = 0.3f;
        public float Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                RecalculateParameters();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            // Draw the gray slider bar
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, _barPos.X, _barPos.Y, _barSize.Width, _barSize.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, _barPos.X, _barPos.Y, _barSize.Width, _barSize.Height);

            // Determine the number of lines and the spacing between them
            int numLines = (int)(Max - Min + 1);
            numLines = 10;
            float lineSpacing = _barSize.Width / numLines;

            // Determine the font size based on the slider height
            float fontSize = Math.Min(16, Height / 4f);
            Font numFont = new Font("Arial", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // Determine the vertical position of the numbers
            float numY = _barPos.Y - numFont.Height;

            for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
            {
                // Calculate the horizontal position of the line and the number
                float lineX = _barPos.X + i * lineSpacing;
                float numX = lineX - numFont.Size / 4f;

                // Draw the white line
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, lineX, _barPos.Y + _barSize.Height + 2f, lineX, _barPos.Y + _barSize.Height + 10f);

                // Draw the number centered under the line
                int number = (int)(Min + i);
                string numberString = number.ToString();

                // Determine the size of the number string
                SizeF numSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(numberString, numFont);

                // Draw the number centered under the line, shifted slightly to the right
                e.Graphics.DrawString(numberString, numFont, Brushes.Black, numX, numY);
            }

            // Draw the red thumb
            GraphicsPath thumbPath = new GraphicsPath();
            thumbPath.AddEllipse(_thumbPos.X - _radius, _thumbPos.Y - _radius, _radius * 2f, _radius * 2f);
            PathGradientBrush thumbBrush = new PathGradientBrush(thumbPath);
            thumbBrush.CenterPoint = new PointF(_thumbPos.X, _thumbPos.Y);
            thumbBrush.CenterColor = Color.White;
            thumbBrush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { Color.Red };
            e.Graphics.FillPath(thumbBrush, thumbPath);

            // Draw the red highlight
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, _thumbPos.X - _radius, _thumbPos.Y - _radius, _radius * 2f, _radius * 2f);
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            RecalculateParameters();
        }

        private void RecalculateParameters()
        {
            _radius = 0.5f * ClientSize.Height;
            _barSize = new SizeF(ClientSize.Width - 2f * _radius, 0.5f * ClientSize.Height);
            _barPos = new PointF(_radius, (ClientSize.Height - _barSize.Height) / 2);
            _thumbPos = new PointF(
                _barSize.Width / (Max - Min) * Value + _barPos.X,
                _barPos.Y + 0.5f * _barSize.Height);
            Invalidate();
        }

        bool _moving = false;
        SizeF _delta;

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);

            // Difference between tumb and mouse position.
            _delta = new SizeF(e.Location.X - _thumbPos.X, e.Location.Y - _thumbPos.Y);
            if (_delta.Width * _delta.Width + _delta.Height * _delta.Height <= _radius * _radius)
            {
                // Clicking inside thumb.
                _moving = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            if (_moving)
            {
                float thumbX = e.Location.X - _delta.Width;
                if (thumbX < _barPos.X)
                {
                    thumbX = _barPos.X;
                }
                else if (thumbX > _barPos.X + _barSize.Width)
                {
                    thumbX = _barPos.X + _barSize.Width;
                }
                Value = (thumbX - _barPos.X) * (Max - Min) / _barSize.Width;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            _moving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

this screenshot show the slider now in the form1 designer:
the numbers are very small.

[image: slider numbers are too small]

then if I'm changing in this line the size for example instead / 4 to / 2 then the numbers are bigger but get swallow:

original line:

```
float fontSize = Math.Min(16, Height / 4f);
```

changed to:

```
float fontSize = Math.Min(16, Height / 2f);
```

the result is:

[image: slider numbers are bigger but get swallow from inside on the top.]

I'm trying to make it as much as automatic calculations logic. so when changing the slider size the numbers size will be changed with the slider too but the numbers size either too small or too big or swallow.